# How to Pass {"generateMasterViews": true} value for IJobPayloadItemAdvanced C#

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, aps

I am trying to translate a revit model to SVF. For a particular model, only when i pass {"generateMasterViews": true}, i am able to translate the file. But i wonder how to define this value in Forge C# API.

I Tried to pass the value for IJobPayloadItemAdvanced, but noluck

Note : I am using Autodesk.Forge 1.9.7 Nuget

Thanks in Advance

Regards,
Chockalingam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's straightforward. Just specify the `JobSvfOutputPayloadAdvanced` with `GenerateMasterViews=true` to the 3rd argument of the `JobPayloadOutput`.

```cs
var urn = "dXJuOm...Ty5ydnQ";
JobPayloadInput jobInput = new JobPayloadInput (urn);

JobSvfOutputPayloadAdvanced advancedConfigs = new JobSvfOutputPayloadAdvanced();
advancedConfigs.GenerateMasterViews = true;

JobPayloadOutput jobOutput = new JobPayloadOutput (
    new List<JobPayloadItem> (
        new JobPayloadItem [] {
                new JobPayloadItem (
                    JobPayloadItem.TypeEnum.Svf,
                    new List<JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum> (
                        new JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum [] {
                            JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._2d, JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._3d
                        }
                    ),
                    advancedConfigs 
                )
        }
    )
);

JobPayload job = new JobPayload (jobInput, jobOutput);
var derivativesAPI = new DerivativesApi();
DerivativesAPI.Configuration.AccessToken = "eyJhbG...";

bool bForce = true;
var response = await derivativesAPI.TranslateAsyncWithHttpInfo (job, bForce);
```